Is it possible to lower the energy of the vacuum?
The energy of the vacuum is given by $$\sum_k \frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega_k.$$ However the frequency $\omega_k$ depends on the wavevector $k$ and some constants like the speed of light $c$, which in turn depends on the permittivity and permeability of free space. I have read about vacuum polarization and that it effectively changes the properties of space. So I was wondering if it is possible to influence these two constants with very strong electric or magnetic fields and thereby change the energy of the vacuum.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I agree with what others have said here, QFT should be learned in university, but to actually answer your question: let's say your description of quantum vacuum energy is correct. No, you can't alter fundamental physical constants, but you can restrict what frequencies $\omega_k$ can exist in a certain region. The Casimir effect, verified by experiment (see Lamoreaux), uses two electrically-conductive plates to restrict the frequency of quanta between them to only those whose frequencies are integer multiples of the distance between them (quantized by the $\hbar$ constant of course).
What you're doing here is saying that certain virtual photons, or regular photons, or whatever exists between those plates can only do so if the frequency is within a certain set of values, so the result is that fewer of those quanta can exist between the two plates than outside of them. Thus an apparent change in the vacuum energy is observed: you don't put mass or an EM field between the plates or anything, but the energy density there decreases.
That last part about not putting EM fields or anything is important. In quantum mechanics (and also general relativity, and also many other physics fields) a vacuum refers to the absence of anything, including both mass in the traditional sense as well as any other particles, including photons that act as EM force carriers; i.e., an EM field precludes the vacuum.

But then how can external electric or magnetic fields modify the Casimir effect. There are papers and if I'm not mistaken even experiments on that subject.

Also I think you misunderstood my question. I wrote it EFFECTIVELY changes the property of space.

@eeqesri If you could provide some references on that statement it would be nice to see where you're coming from. Also, vacuum permeability and permittivity are, well, constants. They aren't measured properties of the vacuum; they are derived from more-fundamental constants, like the speed of light, the fine structure constant, the Planck constant, and the charge of the electron. You can't change the vacuum permeability or permittivity. The closest you can get is reducing the energy in a certain volume relative to the energy outside that volume. And besides, for practical purposes...

...producing the Casimir effect is going to be way cheaper and simpler than polarizing the vacuum. Generally, to account for modifications to the Casimir effect due to EM fields, you need to quantize the EM field with the boundary conditions given by the specific plate setup while also fulfilling conditions that those specific EM fields would create. It involves finding the allowed wavevectors of quanta between the plates and then zeta-regularizing the divergent sum of the energies of quanta with those wavevectors.

the question was not about whether it is cheaper or not. and i say again: I never said that the permittivity and permeability of the vacuum can be changed. I only said effectively. Here is a paper which explains how the presence of an external field modifies the casimir effect. https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9809214

@eeqesri The permittivity and permeability of the vacuum cannot be modified, as far as I'm aware. If you want to change the effective permeability and permittivity in a given region, you can find a material with those permeabilities/permittivities and then fill the region with that material.

Maybe I should have passed it differently. As far as I understand strong enough em fields can polarize the vacuum and change the relative permittivity. That's what I meant by effectively. I don't think the permittivity if discs changes but the relative permittivity. In any case I'm planning on studying QED from a book.
